# How to add/ update custom DNS A Records using Powershell in Office 365/ Azure? So I can update IP address when ISP changes it

Tags: azure, powershell, dns, office365, powershell-cmdlet

Right now I am using Microsoft Office 365 Admin Center to manage the domains and sub domains. But I would like to see if I can add/ update DNS A records to a new IP Address using powershell. this will help updating to a new IP when my ISP assigns one then I can use powershell to update all the "A Records" to reflect the new IP address. Anyone know if this is possible using powershell? Thank you in advance.

Reference on how to do this using UI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/dns/update-dns-records-to-retain-current-hosting-provider?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Have you been through this: https://o365blog.com/post/dns-records/ ? I'm still working on modify this with A records.

Comment: And this: https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm testing, it's not support setting/updatting `A records` to O365 using PowerShell, but `DnsMXRecord` and `DnsTxtRecord` is sopported. Refer to: [Command definition.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoldomainverificationdns?view=azureadps-1.0)

Here is an example of [Add a Domain to Office 365 and Azure using PowerShell](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=679).

It works on my side:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your responses. Yes I saw both your links above as well and I can see it can update the MX and TXT records but I am specifically looking to update the “A Record”. I already have domains added and verified. Need a way to add/ update sub domains / A records.  You think this is not possible? TIA

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, @user1715559 . I have done a lot of research and test, and did not find any feasible solution.

Comment: Thank you for spending the time, appreciate your help. :)

Comment: You're welcome, @user1715559 . Would you mind accept my answer for saving others time?